# C++ Builder XE5: access violation on initialization of GDI+

Tags: c++, gdi+, c++builder

I'm writing simple application with form in Embarcadero XE5 (C++ Builder). It uses GDI+ 1.1. With presence of function (code listed at the bottom) application exits with access violation when initializing (or deinitializing) of GDI+. What can be a reason?

Code:

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#define GDIPVER 0x0110
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;

extern "C"
{
  long int ConvertToPng8File(void* image)
  {
    Gdiplus::Bitmap* newimage = (Gdiplus::Bitmap*)image;
    ColorPalette* pal = (ColorPalette*)malloc(sizeof(ColorPalette) + 255*sizeof(ARGB));
    pal->Count = 256;
    pal->Flags = 0;
    Gdiplus::Bitmap::InitializePalette(pal, PaletteTypeOptimal, 256, false, newimage);
    newimage->ConvertFormat(PixelFormat8bppIndexed, DitherTypeSolid, PaletteTypeOptimal,pal,0);
    free(pal);
  }
}
```

Stack:

```
:0000000077b9e4b4
:0000000077B9E3DB ; ntdll.dll
:000007FEFBFE9EE1 ; C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.17514_none_2b24536c71ed437a\GDIPLUS.DLL
:0000000009af156f ; Winapi::Gdipobj::initialization()
:0000000009bdacb6 ; _init_exit_proc
:0000000009bdaf70 ; _wstartupd
:00000000098f23b6 ; __acrtused
```

Message:

```
First chance exception at $0000000077B9E4B4. 
Exception class $C0000005 with message 'c0000005ACCESS_VIOLATION'.
Process ImageryCreator64.exe (5648)
```

Comment: Try turning off runtime linking while you debug this problem

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace shows that the error occurs during the start-up sequence of your program, before `main` has even been called, i.e. during the initialization of some non-local static GDI object.

You are obviously trying to initialize a static GDI objects, but during static initialization, you have no guarantee on initialization order, or even whether the required libraries are already loaded and initialized: it's the classical [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html).

You need to move the initialization of your GDI-based objects later in the program sequence: either in a some initialization function invoked by `main` or in a [singleton](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CppSingleton).